# Tensorflow Performing Feature Extraction (on the whole Dataset) is very time consuming

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to perform a Feature Extraction on the TensorFlow's standard MNIST dataset, (before training my Neural Network) which is a simple tf.matmul() but it takes about 3 hours to be done. Any tuning tricks or Ideas to reduce the time ?
The code looks like below

```
def apply_feature_extraction(data, feature_mapper):
     weights, bias = feature_mapper
     return session.run(tf.add(tf.matmul(data, weights), bias))

batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
transformed_features = apply_feature_extraction(batch_x, my_feature_mapper)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not create any operations while executing the graph!

Each time when you call `apply_feature_extraction` you put a new operation `tf.add(tf.matmul(...)` to your graph. As a result your graph gets bloated.

First, create a fully defined graph that contains all variables and operations you need and then just execute ops within a `tf.Session` that are defined in the graph.

In your case that might look like this:

```
def apply_feature_extraction(data, feature_mapper):
  weights, bias = feature_mapper
  return tf.add(tf.matmul(data, weights), bias)

batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

# define graph
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None, name='input')
transformed_features = apply_feature_extraction(x, my_feature_mapper)

# execute graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
  trans_feat_evaluated = sess.run(transformed_features, feat_dict={x:batch_x}
```

Comment: J.E.K , Thanks for your help, i just applied your code, but it's still very time consuming, I don't see a drastic change.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue by avoiding *feed_dict* and moving to Datset API:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets